# Heatmap on only a part of the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

I'm trying to make a heatmap plot but would like to omit the first row from it. So that I have a table where the first row wouldn't have any background colour. Somewhat like this [paint example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LJ7c.png)

But I'm not even sure if that is possible. I've tried making a mulitIndex as a column so that the first row would become a part of the column name, but I want the row name, 'fixed' to still be there. Is it even possible?

This is what I'm working with so far. I would appreciate any input!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

SO = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,size=(4,5)))
SO.iloc[0] = [5, 10, 15, 10, 5]
SO.index = ['fixed','val1', 'sd2', 'val2']
SO.columns = ['Prod1', 'Prod2', 'Prod3', 'Prod4', 'Prod5']

sns.set(font_scale=1.5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
ax = sns.heatmap(SO, annot=True, fmt="", cbar=False, cmap="RdYlGn", vmin=0, vmax=100)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=19, labelbottom = False, bottom=False, top = False, labeltop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution, is to plot your first row first, masking the rest, then plot over with the inverse:

This is the mask, where the first row is masked:

```
MASK = SO.apply(lambda x:np.arange(len(x))==0)

        Prod1   Prod2   Prod3   Prod4   Prod5
fixed   True    True    True    True    True
val1    False   False   False   False   False
sd2     False   False   False   False   False
val2    False   False   False   False   False
```

Set a colour for the first row:

```
COL = [(0.9690888119953864, 0.9664744329104191, 0.9649365628604383)]
```

Then we plot:

```
sns.set(font_scale=1.5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
sns.heatmap(SO, annot=True, fmt="", cbar=False, mask=~MASK,cmap=COL,vmin=0, vmax=100,ax=ax)
sns.heatmap(SO, annot=True, fmt="", cbar=False, mask=MASK,cmap="RdYlGn",vmin=0, vmax=100,ax=ax)

plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=19, 
                labelbottom = False, bottom=False, top = False, labeltop=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The masking idea of Stupid Wolf is great, but if you are looking for simpler
ways you can simply incorporate the first row in the column names and plot the heatmap as usual.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

SO = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,size=(4,5)))
SO.iloc[0] = [5, 10, 15, 10, 5]
SO.index = ['fixed','val1', 'sd2', 'val2']
SO.columns = ['Prod1', 'Prod2', 'Prod3', 'Prod4', 'Prod5']
first_row = [str(i) for i in SO.iloc[0]]
labels = [i + '\n' + j for i,j in zip(SO.columns, first_row)]

sns.set(font_scale=1.5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
ax = sns.heatmap(SO.iloc[1:], annot=True, fmt="", cbar=False, cmap="RdYlGn",
                 vmin=0, vmax=100)

ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=19,
                labelbottom = False, bottom=False, top = False, labeltop=True)
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. I want the row to be shown in the plot, but I don't want the heatmap applied to the first row. So that you can see the numbers and the row name, but without any colouring from the heatmap. Is it maybe possible to mask the first row to give a white background?